# Firebase invite only scenario with multiple auth providers

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a Firebase authentication + real time database use case where I would like to register people by invitation only. The initial user creation will be by Email & Password. The users will be invited by sending them an email which includes their password. At this point users can login using their email & password. However, I would like to give them an option to login using a provider and link this account to their email/password account. Firebase makes this very easy. However my issue is that as soon as I open up provider authentication, anyone can register themselves using their provider credentials and access data that is visible to invite only users. How can this be prevented? Is there a better workflow for this scenario?